# Long Shadows of an Image using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to be able to make a long shadow in JS from an image. I've seen ways to do with text online but none with an image(with a transparent background). I have no idea how to approach this without making multiple copies of the image and translating them in the direction I want.

Comment: What you said. Create multiple copies of the image within a canvas and manipulate them.

Comment: @JeffNoel please add your comment as an answer so OP can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution (that I can see) would be to do exactly what you said.

Create multiple copies of the image within a `canvas` element and manipulate them.

Here is an example (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170596/1451422)):

```js
function drawImageWithShadow(img) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('mainCanvas').getContext('2d');
  var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Put your image on a temporary canvas,
  // which will let you create a shadow depending on the shape 
  // of what isn't transparent within your image
  tmpCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Set the shadow properties on the (still empty) canvas.
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
  ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
  ctx.shadowBlur = 5;

  // Add your temporary canvas into the canvas, 
  //which will generate the shadow dynamically depending on the shape of your image.
  ctx.drawImage(tmpCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" onload="drawImageWithShadow(this)" />
<br>
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
```